# How do we know the creation and annihilation operators for angular momentum give rise to a complete basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

In the case of angular momentum in quantum mechanics, a common exercise is to derive the spectrum for $J_z$ and $J^2$. I follow most of this argument, but I get a bit lost at the end.

To my understanding the logic is as follows:

Create an eigenstate of the operators we are searching for the spectrum of. Call this $\vert {J^{2}}', J_{z}' \rangle$ Now, use the total angular momentum relation to write $$J_x^2 + J_y^2 = J^2 - J_z^2$$ We apply this to our function to get $$(J_x^2 + J_y^2)\vert {J^2}', {J_z}' \rangle = (J^2 - J_z^2)\vert {J^2}', {J_z}' \rangle$$ From here, we can deduce that $J_z'$ has an upper and lower bound.

We separately use the commutation relations of the operator to conclude that $$(J_x \pm iJ_y)\vert {J^2}',{J_z}' \rangle$$ is an eigenstate of $J_z$ with eigenvalue ${J_z}' \pm \hbar$ Thus, we have eigenfunctions $${\displaystyle \vert{J^{2}}'J_{z}'\pm \hbar \rangle =(J_{x}\pm iJ_{y})\;\vert {J^{2}}',J_{z}'\rangle.}$$ with bounded eigenvalues. We can also show that, if the lower bound is $J_z^0$ and the upper bound is $J_z^1$, then $J_z^0 = - J_z^0$. Now, here is where I start to get a bit lost.

1. We know that we want to find the spectrum of $J_z$, and we know that the eigenstates take on the form $(J_{x}\pm iJ_{y})\;\vert {J^{2}}',J_{z}'\rangle.$
2. We know that $J_{\pm} = J_x \pm iJ_y$
3. This means the eigenstates are $J_z$ raised and lowered until the upper and lower bounds are met.

I see that in doing all of this, we have constructed a set of eigenstates and that we can find their corresponding eigenvalues. However, I am not sure how we know that these eigenstates form a complete set. How can I be sure of this?

---

I spent a lot of time to think about, type up, and find answers to this question. I don't see any qualms with it - if you are going to vote to close please at least comment why. It's frustrating to put over an hour into a question that just ends up closed for a reason unbeknownst to me.

Comment: I guess, when you say "complete set" you mean complete orthonormal system? Complete orthonormal system of what? The answer to your question depends crucially on the vector space you working with. You should specify this. Selecting *one* eigenvector of $\vec{J}^2$ and $J_z$ in your Hilbert space, the ladder operators $J_\pm$ operate only in the invariant subspace being the representation space of a certain irreducible representation of $SU(2)$.

Comment: Hi @Hyperon, yes I think what you said highlights my confusion. Thus far in my quantum mechanics education, the vector space has always been provided (Hilbert space). In this case, the task is clear to me because I just need to show that whatever set of basis vectors I have spans Hilbert space. However, I feel I am missing this foundation for angular momentum. I do not even know what space I am trying to span. All of the notes/book sections on this just state the task "we want to find the spectrum of $J_z$ and $J^2$", but indeed I'm unsure what space these operators are even defined over.

Answer (score 0):

The *irreducible* representations of the Lie algebra of $\rm SU(2)$ (defined by $[T_k,T_\ell]= i \varepsilon_{k \ell m}T_m$) can be classified by the "weights" $j=0,\, 1/2,\, 1,\, 3/2, \,2, \ldots$. The representation space associated with the weight $j$ is $2j+1$-dimensional, spanned by vectors $$\chi_{-j}, \, \chi_{-j+1}, \ldots, \,\chi_j$$ with $$\vec{T}^2 \chi_m =j(j+1) \chi_m \quad \text{ and} \quad T_3 \chi_m =m \chi_m.$$

Given a (yet to be specified) quantum mechanical Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, the angular momentum operators $\vec{J}$ furnish a (in general *reducible*) representation of the Lie algebra of $\rm SU(2)$, i.e. they satisfy the commutation relations $[J_k,J_\ell]=i\varepsilon_{k \ell m}J_m$ ($\hbar=1$). Assuming that we can find an eigenvector $|\psi \rangle$ of $\vec{J} \cdot \vec{J}$ and $J_3$, the space $\mathcal{D}$ spanned by the vectors $(J_\pm)^n |\psi\rangle$ is a rotation invariant subspace of $\mathcal{H}$, i.e. $$e^{-i \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{J}} \mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{D}.$$  At this point, there are two possibilities. If $\mathcal{D}$ happens to coincide already with $\mathcal{H}$ (being only possible if $\mathcal{H}$ is finite dimensional), the angular momentum operators $\vec{J}$ generate an *irreducible* representation of the Lie algebra of $\rm SU(2)$ with some weight $j$. In this case, the vectors $|j,-j\rangle, \,\ldots ,\, |j,j\rangle$ are already an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{D}$. In general, $\mathcal{D}$ will be a proper subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{D} \ne \mathcal{H}$). In the latter case, $\vec{J}$ are the generators of a *reducible* representation. The full Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ can now be further decomposed into rotation invariant subspaces by choosing some simultaneous eigenvector $|\phi \rangle \in \mathcal{D}^\perp$ of $\vec{J}\cdot\vec{J}$ and $J_3$ in the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{D}$. Continuing this procedure, we can write the original Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ as an orthogonal sum of rotation invariant subspaces associated with irreducible representations of the Lie algebra $\rm su(2)$. A complete orthonormal system of eigenvectors of $\vec{J}\cdot \vec{J}$ and $J_3$ can thus be written in the form $$|j, m, r\rangle, $$ where the index $r$ accounts for the multiplicity of the irreducible representations with weight $j$.

Further details can be found in the relevant text-book literature (see e.g. Roman U. Sexl, Helmuth K. Urbantke, Relativity, Groups, Particles, Springer).